# PHP form is not sending mail if I use mime type and version in header. How to solve this?

Tags: forms, email, html-email

If I use the following code, then the form works fine and I am getting form submissions to my email.

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient="meemail@gmail.com";
    $subject="New request";
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $sender=$_POST["sendername"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
    $message=$_POST["message"];
    $name_title=$_POST["name_title"];   

    $mailBody = "<b>Name:</b> $name_title $sender\n
                 <b>Email:</b> $senderEmail\n\n
                 <b>Message:</b> $message";

    $mail_sent = mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");
}

if ($mail_sent) {
?>
    <p>Mail sent</p>
<?php } ?>
```

If I change the `$mail_sent = mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");` **TO** `$mail_sent = mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>", $headers);`, then the form stops working. What is the issue?

Comment: This will break in WordPress anyway, because you have to use `wp_mail()` to give plugins for server setups a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`From:` is just another mail header. You need to concatenate this with your current `$headers` and pass it as one argument to `mail()`:

```
$headers  = "From: $sender <$senderEmail>\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

// la de da

mail( $recipient, $subject, $mailBody, $headers );
```

Comment: any how it says "unknown sender" http://tinypic.com/r/2h869g6/8

Comment: how can I change that to sender name?

Comment: This seems like a server config issue - PHP `mail` is notoriously variable. You'll have much better luck @ StackOverflow or ServerFault.